# Difference in the receive and send method in a websocket

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, redis, django-channels

I am looking over the following code which does a 'group chat' with different members:

```
# Receive message from WebSocket
def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']

    # Send message to room group
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'message': 'OK'
        }
    )

# Receive message from room group
def chat_message(self, event):
    message = event['message']

    # Send message to WebSocket
    self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'message': message
    }))
```

My questions is what do the two items do? I see that `receive()`, also does the `group_send`, so what purpose does the `chat_message` have if the receive sends it upon receiving it?

Comment: It looks like `chat_message` which is specified in receive, is just the name of the function to call to take action on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That chat server code is a simple example on how to send group messages.

In the code:

```
async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'message': 'OK'
        }
    )
```

this line

```
'type': 'chat_message',
```

is responsible for calling method `chat_message()` with `{ 'message': 'OK'}`

Before sending this message to the group members you may want to modify or check the data, or need to do other stuff. That's why `self.channel_layer.group_send` doesn't directly sends message to the group but calls another method (in this case `chat_message`) to handle sending of message and to keep `receive()` method's code clean.